# How to run shell script commands in an sh file in parallel?

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, parallel-processing, debian

I'm trying to take backup of tables in my database server.

I have around 200 tables. I have a shell script that contains commands to take backups of each table like:

**backup.sh**

```
psql -u username ..... table1 ... file1;
psql -u username ..... table2 ... file2;
psql -u username ..... table3 ... file3;
```

I can run the script and create backups in my machine. But as there are 200 tables, it's gonna run the commands sequentially and takes lot of time. 
I want to run the backup commands in parallel. I have seen articles where in they suggested to use **&&** after each command or use `nohup` command or `wait` command.

But I don't want to edit the script and include around 200 such commands.

Is there any way to run these list of shell script commands parallelly? something like `nodejs` does? Is it possible to do it? Or am I looking at it wrong?

Sample command in the script:

```
psql --host=somehost --port=5490 --username=user --dbname=db -c '\copy dbo.tablename TO "/home/username/Desktop/PostgresFiles/tablename.csv" with DELIMITER ","';
```

Comment: Chances are the database is already giving you tae tables as fast as it can, and attempting to make it do more things at the same time will just produce congestion.

Comment: My shell commands are using \copy which is a client side CSV creation which was working fine when I ran the script normally. But if I use the above mentioned approach, it is considering \copy as COPY which is server side copy for which the db user doesn't have access to.

Comment: @tripleee updated question with sample command in the script.

Comment: That should not happen unless there are things going on which you aren't showing, such as passing the command to a remote shell.

Comment: I tried the command that is mentioned in the below answer by **drldcsta**

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage xargs to run command in parallel, AND control the number of concurrent jobs. Running 200 backup jobs might overwhelm your database, and result in less than optimal performance.

Assuming you have backup.sh with one backup command per line

```
xargs -P5 -I{} bash -c "{}" < backup.sh
```

The commands in backup.sh should be modified to allow quoting (using single quote when possible, escaping double quote):

```
psql --host=somehost --port=5490 --username=user --dbname=db -c '\copy dbo.tablename TO \"/home/username/Desktop/PostgresFiles/tablename.csv\" with DELIMITER \",\"';
```

Where -P5 control the number of concurrent jobs. This will be able to process command lines WITHOUT double quotes. For the above script, you change `"\copy ..."` to `'\copy ...'`

Simpler alternative will be to use a helper `backup-table.sh`, which will take two parameters (table, file), and use

```
xargs -P5 -I{} backup-table.sh "{}" < tables.txt
```

And put all the complex quoting into the backup-table.sh

Comment: I'm getting `psql: warning: extra command-line argument` error for all the words in the script.

Comment: Oops, I did not realize that the full command has double quotes. I've posted small update - but it will require changing double quotes in backup.sh to single quote, as per answer. Hope it will get you more mileage.

Comment: Same issue even after replacing `"` with `'` and `'` with `"`.

Comment: Can you share sample line from backup.txt (after the changes) ?

Comment: Updated in the question. BTW, I'm using Ubuntu. I suppose it shouldn't cause an issue.

Comment: Ubuntu should not be an issue (Mint is based on the same). I've updated suggested quoting for backup.sh. Hopefully it will work - I'm not able to test - I do not have Postgrsql running

Answer (score 1):

```
doit() {
  table=$1
  psql --host=somehost --port=5490 --username=user --dbname=db -c '\copy dbo.'$table' TO "/home/username/Desktop/PostgresFiles/'$table'.csv" with DELIMITER ","';
}
export -f doit

sql --listtables -n postgresql://user:pass@host:5490/db | parallel -j0 doit
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any logic in the script other than individual commands? (EG: and `if`'s or processing of output?).

If it's just a file with a list of scripts, you could write a wrapper for the script (or a loop from the CLI) EG:

```
$ cat help.txt
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3

$ while read -r i;do bash -c "$i" &done < help.txt
[1] 18772
[2] 18773
[3] 18774
1
2
3
[1]   Done                    bash -c "$i"
[2]-  Done                    bash -c "$i"
[3]+  Done                    bash -c "$i"

$ while read -r i;do bash -c "$i" &done < help.txt
[1] 18820
[2] 18821
[3] 18822
2
3
1
[1]   Done                    bash -c "$i"
[2]-  Done                    bash -c "$i"
[3]+  Done                    bash -c "$i"
```

Each line of `help.txt` contains a command and I run a loop where I take each command and run it in subshell. (this is a simple example where I just background each job. You could get more complex using something like `xargs -p` or `parallel` but this is a starting point)

Comment: My shell commands are using `\copy` which is a client side CSV creation which was working fine when I ran the script normally. But if I use the above mentioned approach, it is considering `\copy` as `COPY` which is server side copy for which the db user doesn't have access to.

Comment: You need to use `read -r` to have `read` not mangle backslashes. You really basically always want the `-r` option with `read` unless you specifically require the wacky legacy behavior from the original `sh`.